# Step's Chunks Concurrently with Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

It's super easy to make Step's Chunks run concurrently by just adding task executor in step bean declaration like so:

```
@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor(){
    SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("taskExecutor");
    taskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(5);
    return taskExecutor;
}

@Bean
public Step logGroupedDeductionStep(){
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("logGroupedDeductionStep")
            .<DeductionType, GroupedDeductionTransactionDTO>chunk(50)
            .reader(groupedDeductionItemReader)
            .processor(groupedDeductionItemProcessor)
            .writer(groupedDeductionItemWriter)
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .build();
}
```

In my reader, processor and writer i use `Spring Data JPA` to fetch and write data to persistence layer (MySQL).

My question is, if i do just that, does that mean that the different threads will be reading the same entities at some point thus duplicate records will be written as a result ?

How is it possible to make processing(and writing) to happen in different thread but reader to be one(like source of data)?

Please shade some light.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Locking`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#locking) in `JPA` to restrict concurrent clients to asynchronoulsy alter your entities.

```
interface UserRepository extends Repository<User, Long> {

    // Plain query method
    @Lock(LockModeType.READ)
    List<User> findByLastname(String lastname);

}
```

[This](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-java-persistence-locking/) blog explains why/when to use `Locking`.